# Flatten two lists of dicts by matching inner dicts property in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

**Background:**
I'm getting some data from the backend (`regions =[]`) and I need to add a property `(order = [])` to each dict in the list by matching slug. Where I will sort by this property in the jinja template filter.

In javascript I would use a functional Array methods like `map`, `zip` etc; unfortunately, I'm a python noob and I don't know what's the equivalent of these methods.

### **Question:**

**How can I concisely flatten the list `order` into `regions` and receive the expected output `regions_with_order` in python?**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/GummyPartialKoala)

```
# I made this to zip into regions
order = [
  {'slug': 'north-america', 'order': 1},
  {'slug': 'latin-america', 'order': 2},
  {'slug': 'europe', 'order': 3},
  {'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'order': 4},
  {'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'order': 5},
]

# I received this from backend cms.   
regions = [
  {'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'lat': '123'},     
  {'slug': 'europe','lat': '1231'},
  {'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'lat': '1230'},
  {'slug': 'latin-america',  'lat': '1232'},
  {'slug': 'north-america', 'lat': '1234'},
]



# Expected OUTPUT

# regions_with_order = [
#   {'slug': 'north-america', 'lat': '1234',  'order': 1},
#   {'slug': 'latin-america',  'lat': '1232',  'order': 2},
#   {'slug': 'europe','lat': '1231', 'order': 3},
#   {'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'lat': '1230','order': 4},
#   {'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'lat': '123','order': 5}
# ]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?

Comment: I've removed the FP tag sorry

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: We are using Python 2.7 :(

Comment: Will the slugs be unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the regions list to a dictionary first, so you can look up the `lat` value per region by slug, *efficiently*:

```
def merge_dicts(d1, *ds):
    final = d1.copy()
    for d in ds:
        final.update(d)
    return final

regionmap = {r['slug']: r for r in regions}
regions_with_order = [merge_dicts(o, regionmap[o['slug']]) for o in order]
```

In Python 3, you can replace the `merge_dicts()` call with `{**o, **regionmap[o['slug']]}`.

This produces your desired output:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> order = [
...   {'slug': 'north-america', 'order': 1},
...   {'slug': 'latin-america', 'order': 2},
...   {'slug': 'europe', 'order': 3},
...   {'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'order': 4},
...   {'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'order': 5},
... ]
>>> regions = [
...   {'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'lat': '123'},
...   {'slug': 'europe','lat': '1231'},
...   {'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'lat': '1230'},
...   {'slug': 'latin-america',  'lat': '1232'},
...   {'slug': 'north-america', 'lat': '1234'},
... ]
>>> regionmap = {r['slug']: r['lat'] for r in regions}
>>> [merge_dicts(o, regionmap[o['slug']]) for o in order]
[{'slug': 'north-america', 'order': 1, 'lat': '1234'}, {'slug': 'latin-america', 'order': 2, 'lat': '1232'}, {'slug': 'europe', 'order': 3, 'lat': '1231'}, {'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'order': 4, 'lat': '1230'}, {'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'order': 5, 'lat': '123'}]
>>> pprint(_)
[{'lat': '1234', 'order': 1, 'slug': 'north-america'},
 {'lat': '1232', 'order': 2, 'slug': 'latin-america'},
 {'lat': '1231', 'order': 3, 'slug': 'europe'},
 {'lat': '1230', 'order': 4, 'slug': 'asia-pacific'},
 {'lat': '123', 'order': 5, 'slug': 'africa-middle-east'}]
```

Comment: what if `regions` keys are length(n)... how can i just spread the properties to the final output w/o documenting every one in the list comprehension(??) I dunno what I'm saying in python?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: this is a O(N) solution, N being the number of items in the `order` list. Dictionary lookups are O(1).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean it like that.  I meant what if the original regions had more properties than my contrived example.  {slug, lat, long, ...n}. `regionmap = {r['slug']: r['lat'] for r in regions}` isn't possible with that in mind.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: then just store the whole map: `regionmap = {r['slug']: r for r in regions}`.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: I've updated the answer to include a full dict merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
order = [
  {'slug': 'north-america', 'order': 1},
  {'slug': 'latin-america', 'order': 2},
  {'slug': 'europe', 'order': 3},
  {'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'order': 4},
  {'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'order': 5}
]

regions = [
  {'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'lat': '123'},

  {'slug': 'europe','lat': '1231'},
  {'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'lat': '1230'},
  {'slug': 'latin-america',  'lat': '1232'},
  {'slug': 'north-america', 'lat': '1234'},
]
final_data = [{'slug':i['slug'], 'lat':i['lat'], 'order':[c['order'] for c in order if c['slug'] == i['slug']][0]} for i in regions]
```

Output:

```
[{'lat': '123', 'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'order': 5}, 
{'lat': '1231', 'slug': 'europe', 'order': 3}, 
{'lat': '1230', 'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'order': 4}, 
{'lat': '1232', 'slug': 'latin-america', 'order': 2}, 
{'lat': '1234', 'slug': 'north-america', 'order': 1}]
```

If the regions are of arbitrary length, you can try this in Python3:

```
new_list = sorted([{**i, **{'order':[c['order'] for c in order if c['slug'] == i['slug']][0]}} for i in regions], key=lambda x:x['order'])
```

Output:

```
[{'slug': 'north-america', 'lat': '1234', 'order': 1}, 
{'slug': 'latin-america', 'lat': '1232', 'order': 2}, 
{'slug': 'europe', 'lat': '1231', 'order': 3}, 
{'slug': 'asia-pacific', 'lat': '1230', 'order': 4}, 
{'slug': 'africa-middle-east', 'lat': '123', 'order': 5}]
```

Comment: what if regions properties are length(n)...  do I need to document every one of them?

Comment: You changed the order from the desired output; the `order` ordering is desired, not the `region` ordering. And your approach does a full scan of the `order` list *for each region*, so this is a O(NM) solution, while mine is a straight linear approach.

Comment: @MartijnPieters dictionaries are unordered, if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: @Ajax1234: `order` and `regions` are not dictionaries, they are lists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters correct, where you originally referring to how the OP wants them sorted?

Comment: Why the sort? `order` is *already* in the correct order. You only got the wrong order because you iterate over `regions` instead.